# problems on multithreading with OpenMP

Tags: slurm

```
#SBATCH --time=8:30:00 
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -c 24
#SBATCH --output=wf22N-%j.out
#SBATCH --error=wf22N-%j.err
#SBATCH --mail-type=all
#SBATCH --mail-user=
module load pre2019
cd $PWD
module load mkl/18.0.4  gcc/5.2.0  openmpi/gnu/3.1.4.4  blas/netlib/intel  lapack/netlib/intel
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=24
ulimit -s unlimited
srun /nfs/home/xx/quip
```

I tried to do multithreading calculation with OpenMP. I submitted the batch script. But get an error:

**srun: error: Attempt to run a job step with pack group value of 1, but the job allocation has maximum value of 0**

Is there any problem with the batch file?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using [srun](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html) from the Slurm Workload Manager? If so, I think you have the wrong tags.

Comment: @DanielDearlove thanks for your reply. Yes, I use srun from slurm workload manager.  Which tags are wrong?